# Console Command options shall not remove whitespaces

Tags: php, bash, symfony, console, symfony-console

I have a command within a bash-script:

```
/usr/bin/env php foo.php $@
```

With this option:

```
$this->addOption(
    'prefix',
    null,
    InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL,
    'Prefix for each commit message',
    '- '
);
```

When I run the command

```
bin/foo some:command --prefix 'Meh '
bin/foo some:command --prefix "Meh "
bin/foo some:command --prefix='Meh '
bin/foo some:command --prefix="Meh "
```

And take a look at the option

```
var_dump( $input->getOption('prefix') );
```

Then it trims the whitespaces

```
string(3) "Meh"
```

Why is that?
How do I suppress that or correctly put the options in my command?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. It is

```
/usr/bin/env php foo.php "$@"
```

The quotes are important

Comment: You should mark your own answer as the right one :)